# how to create and connect slot in Qt to TCP recv() without using QTcpSockets?

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

I want to create a slot in Qt or something similar in C++ for recv() function in TCP,so that when the socket receive the data it will call the slot automatically,I can do it by using QTcpSockets but I can't use them due to some limitations.currently i am using timer to receive data from recv() function.

Please guide me in right direction.

tcp.h

```
    ifndef TCP_H
    #define TCP_H

    #pragma once
    #include <WinSock2.h>
    #include <WS2tcpip.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include "config.h"
    #include "tcp_packets.h"
    #include "change_ending.h"
    #include "md5.h"
    #pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

    class CTcpClient
    {
    private:
    char* szServerName;
    char*   Port;
    SOCKET ConnectSocket;
    md5checksum Md5Var;

    public:
        int Size;
        bool Send(char* szMsg,int len);
        CTcpClient(char* servername,char* port)
        {
            Port=port;
            szServerName = servername;
            ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
            Size=0;


        }

        bool Start();
        void Stop();
        // Free the resouces




        // Receive message from server
         char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFFER_PKT_LENGTH];
        void Recv();


    };
```

tcp.cpp

```
    #endif // TCP_H
tcp.cpp
#include "tcp.h"
#include "config.h"

bool CTcpClient::Start() {
        WSADATA wsaData;

        // Initialize Winsock
        int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
        if(iResult != 0)
        {
            printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
            return false;
        }

        struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
                        *ptr = NULL,
                        hints;

        ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
        hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
        hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
        //hints.ai_protocol = SOL_SOCKET;
        //Resolve the server address and port
        iResult = getaddrinfo(szServerName,Port, &hints, &result);
        if (iResult != 0)
        {
            printf("getaddrinfo failed: %d\n", iResult);
            WSACleanup();
            return false;
        }

        ptr = result;

        // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
        ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_protocol);


        if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            printf("Error at socket(): %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            freeaddrinfo(result);
            WSACleanup();
            return false;
        }

        // Connect to server
        iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);

        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
        }

        freeaddrinfo(result);

        if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
            WSACleanup();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
void CTcpClient::Stop() {
        int iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);

        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("shutdown failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        }

        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
    }
bool CTcpClient::Send(char* szMsg,int len)
    {

        int iResult = send(ConnectSocket, szMsg, len, 0);

        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            Stop();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
void CTcpClient::Recv()
    {



        int iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, DEFAULT_REC_BUFFER_PKT_LENGTH, 0);
        Size=iResult;
        if (iResult > 0)
        {
            char msg[DEFAULT_REC_BUFFER_PKT_LENGTH];
            memset(&msg, 0, sizeof(msg));
            strncpy(msg, recvbuf, iResult);

            printf("Received: %s\n", msg);


        }


        //return false;
    }
```

Comment: It will only work if you poll the connection yourself and manually call the slot.

Comment: Have you tried using readyread() signal?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg  is there some way in c++ that can trigger my Recv function when socket receive the data.

Comment: No, C++ doesn't have that functionality. The operating system may have functionality for that (search e.g. for "asynchronous sockets <your operating system>"), and of course using external libraries specifically designed for it (like the Qt network library which you apparently can't use).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can, you may create separate thread for Recv() function and give it callback function as parameter. Then in separate thread call callback function every time you get data from socket.

```
void callback(char *data){
     printf("Received: %s\r\n", data);
}
void* thread_function(void *input){
     void (*callb)(char*) = (void (*)(char*))input;
     int recieve;
     while(1){
          receive = recv();
          if(receive > 0)
               callb();
     }
return NULL;
}
int main(){
pthread_t thread;
pthread_create(thread, NULL, thread_function, &callback);
/* do some stuff */
pthread_join(thread);
return 0;
}
```

Something like this. A lot of variables and arguments are missing, but it shows main idea.